# Disabling anonymous bind on ApacheDS LDAP causes getent group not to work

Tags: 14.04, ldap, client

Am new to ApacheDS - am using apacheds-2.0.0-M17.

Followed the instructions to setup an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine as a LDAP client from this page:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LDAPClientAuthentication

Was able to view groups by issuing the following command:

```
getent group
```

I then proceeded by disabling anonymous bind by going into the Ubuntu machine which is running apacheds using ldapmodify:

```
ldapmodify -H ldap://my_target_server:10389 -D "uid=admin,ou=system" -x -W

dn: ads-directoryServiceId=default,ou=config
changetype: modify
replace: ads-dsallowanonymousaccess
ads-dsallowanonymousaccess: FALSE
```

After restarting apacheds, I verified that I was not able to login anonymously by using this particular ldapsearch query:

```
ldapsearch -H ldap://my_target_server:10389 -x -b "dc=iam,dc=aws,dc=org"
```

Which resulted in the following output in stdout:

```
 ldap_bind: Invalid credentials (49)
      additional info: INVALID_CREDENTIALS: Bind failed: ERR_268 Cannot find a partition for
```

Now, when I issue the command for

```
getent group
```

Nothing from my target LDAP server returns!

Question(s):

1. Is my ldapmodify process the correct way to turn off / disable anonymous binding?
2. How can I view my groups using getent group (from the client machine) with anonymous binding turned off? Is there a way to specify the password for the LDAP target server when issuing getent group?

My /etc/nsswitch.conf looks like this:

```
passwd:         compat
group:          compat
shadow:         compat

hosts:          files dns
networks:       files

protocols:      db files
services:       db files
ethers:         db files
rpc:            db files

netgroup:       nis
```

When I enabled the anonymous access by setting the

```
ads-dsallowanonymousaccess: TRUE
```

I was able view my LDAP groups by issuing:

```
getent group
```

Need to able to turn off anonymous binding (and still view groups using getent) without using the Apache Directory Studio application.

Thank you for taking the time to read this.